# PHP YII prettyPhoto Button Click

Tags: php, button, click, yii, prettyphoto

I am using prettyPhoto to create a slideshow of images on website & is working fine by clicking on images.
But I want to create a Button Click Event by which slide show automatically starts from image 1 to n.

Comment: How've you tried and what does not work in your code?

Comment: Thanks PLB for concern.Actually I want to create a Submit Button so that user clicks on it & slide show of Image starts working instead a user has to click on particular image to start slide show of prettyPhoto.

Comment: you can set the autoplay_slideshow property to true which starts the slideshow automatically.

Comment: I am not familiar with `prettyPhoto` but I can think how it can be working. When user click on image arises event that shows image. So if you write little javascript script that simulates user click event, you'll get auto play.

Comment: Well I am not familiar with JQuery.By the way Thanks PLB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the autoplay_slideshow to true which enables the slideshow when you load.

If that is not an option take a look at the [PrettyPhoto Documentation](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/), in particular the customisation section. Add your button markup to markup property.

Another option can be to create a button with your own JS which periodically calls the prettyphoto public API functions such as `$.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');`

Comment: I have Got the answer It will be done by using href="#inline" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]".